# ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable but telnet and tnsping works

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, telnet, tnsnames

Last days  i stay face to face with a strange oracle problem.
I have defined database in tnsnames.ora. Oracle client is installed , client and client/bin have been added to PATH.

`Ping` works, `tnsping` works, I can connect to host by database port with telnet.

When I try to run application that tries to connect to db I got

> ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

It is the same situation when I try to connect by sqlplus

> sqlplus username/password@TNSNAME

Situation occurred only on one workstation, it's mean in common it should works.

WS is windows 7 64 bit.
Database :

> Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple oracle clients installed (so multiple TNS Names.ora), the application is using one and the command line another?

Comment: Do you have IPv6 enabled? That might be a problem with 10g.

Comment: Yes i have two oracle clients, tnsnames files are the same. To be sure in PATH i leave only one client reference.

Comment: tnsping shows where it got the parameter sqlnet.ora from. Where did it find the parameter file? That should be next to the tnsnames.ora that is actually used.

Comment: One of the reason is you have used @ character somewhere in password.

Answer (score 15):

I also faced the same issue ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

i resolved it in this way

open sqlplus

connect

enter user-name :system
enter password : HHHHH@2014

then the following error raised

the problem is my password contains @ symbol

resolved it by putting my password in "HHHHHH@2014"

Comment: Thanks it help for me. Keep password in double quote:)

Comment: its work for me too. Thanks. I have installed oracle server 11g XE.

Comment: It worked me as well for connecting to SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same problem, I resolved it by changing my password and removing "@" character. It worked for me.

@ is to tell SQL plus which connection identifier (service name/sid) we want to connect. In short, avoid using this character in password.

Comment: can you please tell me how you changed your Oracle System Password?

Comment: @idiotduffer: You can refer to below blog on how to escape "@" character. 
Sample: sqlplus scott/\”scott@test\”@TEST_DB
http://nadvi.blogspot.my/2011/02/oracle-password-with-or-special.html. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I too got ORA-12543 :TNS :destination host unreachable. 
But for me the problem was in the password.

Resolution : Need to remove "@" from the existing password as
@ defines connection identifier being used to connect in sqlPlus.

To update the password , follow below steps :
Logon to window cmd then type "sqlplus /nolog"
then "connect / as sysdba" .
Once you are connected,  change the SYS password to something without @: 
"ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY new_password;"

Answer (score 2):

(log in as sys dba)

> sql>conn / as sysdba

(then alter the user)

> sql>alter user username identified by newuserName
>
> sql>commit

(now again try to login with new user with the same password it will work)
click on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkRN.png) to see the screenshot -- [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fkRN.png)

Comment: you mean *newusername* or new password?

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I installed Oracle 11g for testing purpose and after completion of installation **Database 11g Express Edition** started on the browser with the system and Pravin@01 password it is connected successfully. After I tried using SQL Developer tool it was also working fine but while I tried to connect using ***SQL PLUS command line tool*** it suddenly gave me an error as,

---

> ORA-12543: TNS:destination host unreachable

---

Then after research for an hour, I got a solution that Oracle treats @ character in the password as a `

> `service name or sid`

so the solution for this problem is to remove @ character from the password using

> **ALTER USER system IDENTIFIED BY ' here is your new password which should contain character 
>    and digits only try to eliminate special characters';**

I think this post may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this in Windows 2016 environment with Oracle 18c 64-bit

Use this following escape character sequence when attempting to logon with an "@" in the password.

user: scott
password: scott@test

```
sqlplus scott/\”scott@test\”@TEST_DB
```

In order avoid this annoyance, change password without an @ character using the following command once you have logged in to sqlplus.

```
alter user scott identified by "newpassword"
```

Comment: thanks you mate. you saved my day :thumpup !

Comment: http://nadvi.blogspot.com/2011/02/oracle-password-with-or-special.html has more details

Answer (score 1):

Your current password must be containing "@" symbol and that's the problem.
So, just reset your password and dont use this symbol in your new password.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to comments, if your current password contains "@" symbol then you need to reset password;
how to do step:
open sqlPlus
In enter username enter: / AS SYSDBA;
(connected to oracle)
reset in by:
ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY new_password;

Answer (score 0):

Use **URL Encoding for special characters in your password** instead of raw special characters **while connecting through terminal**.

**Example :-**

if your connection string is :- **sqlplus system/Password@12345@oracle as sysdba;**

**Then**

Acceptable connection url will be :- **sqlplus system/Password%4012345@oracle as sysdba;**. Here **%40** is the **URL Encoding** for **@**, so replace all special characters with their respective URL Encoding and execute the connection command in terminal.